# How to avoid the null array from json values?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 if(arrSubCategory.count>0||arrSubCategory!=Nil)
            {
            for (NSDictionary *dicsub in arrSubCategory)
            {
                [dicSubCategory setObject:[dicsub objectForKey:@"category_id"] forKey:@"category"];
                [dicSubCategory setObject:[dicsub objectForKey:@"parent_id"] forKey:@"parent"];
                [dicSubCategory setObject:[dicsub objectForKey:@"image"] forKey:@"image"];
                [dicSubCategory setObject:[dicsub objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
                  NSLog(@"sub category parsing%@",dicSubCategory);
                [file addSubCategories:dicSubCategory];
            }
```

here i am checking the array count is greater than zero then the condition have to check.

->but what happens mean

```
(
  ()
)
```

one empty array has been get storing in my array,how to avoid this empty from my json values.

Comment: this check may help,    if ([arrSubCategory]== [NSNull null])

Comment: @Mumthezir its giving me a warning ..nsmutablearray to null....

Answer (score 0):

You can check the object in arr is `NSDictionary` or not

```
 for (NSDictionary *dicsub in arrSubCategory) 
 {
     if([dicsub isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
     {
            [dicSubCategory setObject:[dicsub objectForKey:@"category_id"] forKey:@"category"];
            [dicSubCategory setObject:[dicsub objectForKey:@"parent_id"] forKey:@"parent"];
            [dicSubCategory setObject:[dicsub objectForKey:@"image"] forKey:@"image"];
            [dicSubCategory setObject:[dicsub objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
            NSLog(@"sub category parsing%@",dicSubCategory);
            [file addSubCategories:dicSubCategory];
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if Object is nil, you should check if its count is zero.

Try this way :

```
NSArray *arr = [DicWholeCategories objectForKey:@"subcategory"];

if(arr.count > 0)
{
   [arrSubCategory addObject:arr];
}
```

Comment: [arrSubCategory addObject:[DicWholeCategories objectForKey:@"subcategory"]!=Nil ?[DicWholeCategories objectForKey:@"subcategory"]:@""];

Comment: yes i have checking but this not working for me @Faisal Tanveer

Comment: Do you use NSLog to print JSON response? first check the format of JSON data. Empty array might be there in your json.

Comment: Can you post your JSON here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88862/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-faisal-tanveer).

Comment: This is no answer and should be placed in a comment.

Comment: then it will like this (({}))

Comment: How this answer has up votes ? FYI the questioner is also checking for `array.count`.

Answer (score 0):

**Lots of Mistakes:**

First of all your condition is wrong. It should be

```
if(arrSubCategory.count > 0 && !arrSubCategory)
```

You will need an `&&` operator here instead of `||` because both condition should be true means array count should be greater than 0 and it should not be `nil` to proceed.

Comparison of an object with `Nil` is also wrong it should be `nil`.

Second thing don't compare any object with `nil` like `(object != nil)` better to use just `(!object)`.

Last thing if you want to check the object is `null` or not use `isKindOfClass:` method which returns a `BOOL` value.

```
if (![arrSubCategory isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

Well to avoid the empty array just one line is enough:

```
if ([arrSubCategory count] > 0)
```